# AWS EKS add user restricted to namespace

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I have created AWS EKS cluster since I have created using my AWS userID has been added to `system:masters` group. But when checked ConfigMap `aws-auth` I don't see my user ID. **Why ?**

I had to give access to another user, so I have to assign appropriate AWS policies to the IAM user, then I edited the ConfigMap `aws-auth` with the following mapping

```
mapUsers:
----
- userarn: arn:aws:iam::573504862059:user/abc-user  
  username: abc-user
  groups:
    - system:masters
```

So far I have understood when a user is part of `system:masters` group, this user has admin privileges on the cluster.

How can I **add a new user who will have restricted privileges** to a specific namespace? Do I have to do the same thing what I have done for the above user? If so then what group I should add the new user to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would familiarize with [Kubernetes RBAC concepts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)

So you can create a `Role` since these are limited to a specific namespace.

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: my-namespace
  name: full-namespace
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"] 
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

Then create a `RoleBinding`:

```
$ kubectl create rolebinding my-namespace-binding --role=full-namespace --group=namespacegroup --namespace=my-namespace
```

Or `kubectl create -f` this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-namespace-binding
  namespace: mynamespace
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: full-namespace
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Group
  name: namespacegroup
```

Then on your ConfigMap:

```
mapUsers:
----
- userarn: arn:aws:iam::573504862059:user/abc-user  
  username: abc-user
  groups:
    - namespacegroup
```

Comment: Added more details to the answer

Comment: in roleBinding yaml file subjects section with Group should contain: `name: namespacegroup` instead of  `namespace: mynamespace`