# Adding IAM Group to aws-auth configmap in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

The [aws-auth configmap](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) in AWS EKS performs a mapping between IAM users/roles to kubernetes RBAC roles. However, the documentation does not specify anything on adding IAM groups to the configmap.

We use multiple namespaces, each namespace managed by a different team. I created a set of kubernetes RBAC roles, limited to the different namespaces. Now I want to give everbody in the teams IAM group that specific role.

Is it possible to add IAM groups in the aws-auth configmap? If not, what would the proposed solution be? Create a IAM role per team and allow only members of the IAM group the permission to assume that role?

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62262710/enabling-aws-group-to-access-aws-eks-cluster

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765737/10675601).

TLDR
1. Create a role that allows full API access
2. Create a `RoleBinding` for that role to your target namespace with a named apiGroup as the `subjects`.
3. Add an entry for your IAM user in the aws-auth `ConfigMap` to add the `mapUser` to the named aforementioned apiGroup.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I have the RoleBindings with a named group within the namespaces. However, I wonder if instead of adding individual IAM users, I can add an IAM group to the aws-auth ConfigMap. Would I be able to specify the IAM group arn in the mapUSer section?

Comment: @Blokje5 I would also like to know if I can add an IAM group to the was-auth ConfigMap. Any luck?

Comment: @Squirrel not yet, I am solving it with roles instead now. Not ideal, but it does work for our use cases.

Comment: @Blokje5 I'm trying also the role approach but am unable to get it working. I posted a duplicate question with additional context here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62262710/1466456. Did you follow the same approach? Thank you!

Comment: You can only add roles to the aws-auth config map