# Enabling AWS Group to access AWS EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

This question is essentially a duplicate of [Adding IAM Group to aws-auth configmap in AWS EKS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55455125/1466456). However, the question does not have an accepted answer and I would like to provide more context.

I know that `aws-auth` ConfigMap object does not allow mapping AWS Group directly. A workaround would be to map an AWS Role instead. I tried that but were unable to get it working. Mapping an AWS User works without issues.

I setup an AWS Role `arn:aws:iam::027755483893:role/development-readwrite` with account `027755483893` as being the trusted entity and attached the following trust policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::027755483893:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I setup an AWS Group `arn:aws:iam::027755483893:group/development-readwrite` and attached the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::027755483893:role/development-readwrite"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I setup the `aws-auth` ConfigMap as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    # Other mappings omitted for clarity
    - groups:
      - system:masters
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::027755483893:role/development-readwrite
  mapUsers: |
    []
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-08-21T08:25:15Z"
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "62031092"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/aws-auth
  uid: 33b33620-c3ed-11e9-83c0-029bc9dcca16
```

However, none of the users in the group have access to the cluster. Do the users need to explicitly assume role? Is there anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case the users indeed need to explicitly assume the role. The fact that the users can assume the role is not enough for them to actually have access to the cluster.

One approach that can simplify it for your users is by [creating a kubeconfig with the `aws get token` call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html#create-kubeconfig-manually). This allows you to specify a role_arn of a role to assume for the cluster.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I will either introduce a shared kubeconfig with the token call or fall back to mapping users directly to keep new developer setup simple.

Comment: According to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html#create-kubeconfig-manually one can add an optional entry in the kube config, to assume a certain role.